# Bitmask with weights

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have following pairs:

```
pairs = [(1,9),(5,5),(6,4),(2,8)]
```

From the pair I can take only one element. I need to generate n lists of binary mask combinations with minimal sum, where `0` for first element and `1` for second.

Output of provided example if n == 5:
`[0,0,1,0], [0,1,1,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,1]`

Is it kind of [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)? What is the best algorithm for doing this?

Comment: to make sure I understand, if you had n=3 for example, you would have [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0] and [0, 0, 1, 1] ?

Comment: @Mitchnoff No, `[0,0,1,0], [0,1,1,0], [0,0,0,0]` Those are the combinations with minimal sum. `0,0,1,0` has the smallest sum, `0,1,1,0` the second smallest and `0,0,0,0` the third smallest.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why only those 3?

Comment: @Mitchnoff You asked for `n=3`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, I mean why when n=3 do you end up with those 3 lists

Comment: @Mitchnoff Can you find any list where the sum of the corresponding elements is less than when using those three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the code below is to enumerate the sorted combinations
recursively (well, not using recursion) for the tail of the pairs list,
then do a sorted merge between the combinations that use the lesser
element of the first pair and the combinations that use the greater
element of the first pair. The space requirement is minimized using
generators (should generally be on the order of the number of elements
you take).

```py
import collections
import itertools


def extend_sorted(pair, sequence):
    argmin_pair = min(range(2), key=pair.__getitem__)
    min_pair = pair[argmin_pair]
    argmax_pair = 1 - argmin_pair
    max_pair = pair[argmax_pair]
    buffer = collections.deque()
    for sub_combo, sub_total in sequence:
        while buffer and buffer[0][1] < min_pair + sub_total:
            yield buffer.popleft()
        yield ([argmin_pair] + sub_combo, min_pair + sub_total)
        buffer.append(([argmax_pair] + sub_combo, max_pair + sub_total))
    while buffer:
        yield buffer.popleft()


def enumerate_least_sums(pairs):
    sequence = [([], 0)]
    for pair in reversed(pairs):
        sequence = extend_sorted(pair, sequence)
    for combo, total in sequence:
        yield combo


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(*itertools.islice(enumerate_least_sums([(1, 9), (5, 5), (6, 4), (2, 8)]), 5))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0] [0, 1, 1, 0] [0, 0, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0] [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have several questions:  1) Could you please comment on how does `extend_sorted` generator work? It has 3 yield options, I don't understand in what case we use each of them. 2) Also I don't understand how you maintain the length of mask, how it happens that in the same `buffer` we have `sequence` of different length but we end up with correct length of len(pairs) never explicitly awaiting it.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ The first and third yields emit masks that use the max; the second yield emits masks that use the min. The buffer holds masks that use the max for which we've already emitted the corresponding mask with the min. We drain the max-masks that come before the next min-mask and then emit the min-mask. Finally we emit the leftover max-masks.